# hidden text is not visible on button first click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage with a button and a paragraph of text. A click on the button should show or hide the paragraph. When the paragraph is shown initially, everything works fine. But when the paragraph is hidden, the first click has no consequence - the code works fine from the second click on. Why? How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```js
function show_hide(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display == '') {
    e.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    e.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="show_hide('text_to_show_hide')" value="Show/Hide">
<p id="text_to_show_hide" class="hidden">This is the text that I want to show/hide.</p>
```

Comment: Toggle may not work for Internet Explorer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Remove `|| e.style.display==''` from the `if`. Because you set your css to have `display:none`, an empty string will fail. You just need to check if it's block or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need consistency. you are starting off the paragragh with the class `hidden`, which keeps the paragraph hidden, but does not have the 'display' property on the inline style.

either add and remove the hidden class:

```js
function show_hide(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  e.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="show_hide('text_to_show_hide')" value="Show/Hide">
 
<p id="text_to_show_hide" class="hidden">This is the text that I want to show/hide.</p>
```

OR use only inline styles

```js
function show_hide(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display==''){
    e.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    e.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="show_hide('text_to_show_hide')" value="Show/Hide">
 
<p id="text_to_show_hide" style='display:none'>This is the text that I want to show/hide.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution, and even more so for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`style.display` object always check the inline style value

The issue is you have used `e.style.display == ''` in the first condition which is making the condition true first time because there is no display value at the first DOM load

Try to remove `e.style.display == ''` from your condition...

```js
function show_hide(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'block') {
    e.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    e.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="show_hide('text_to_show_hide')" value="Show/Hide">
<p id="text_to_show_hide" class="hidden">This is the text that I want to show/hide.</p>
```

Comment: Many thanks. This solved my problem. That said (for my understanding), the same code starting with display:block would have the same problem on first click, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function show_hide(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  
  e.classList.toggle("hidden");
   }
```

```css
.hidden{
        display:none;
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="show_hide('text_to_show_hide')" value="Show/Hide">
 
<p id="text_to_show_hide" class="hidden">This is the text that I want to show/hide.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to avoid using toggle because of the issues with Internet Explorer.

Comment: You can easily find a shim for it online

Comment: Anyways, it has been a pleasure

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct that you're only checking the inline display value which is causing the issues, but there is a better way than forcing your element to only use inline styles. Just use getComputedStyle instead.

```
if (window.getComputedStyle(e, null).getPropertyValue("display") == 'none' || window.getComputedStyle(e, null).getPropertyValue("display") == ''){
  e.style.display = 'block';
}

else{
  e.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Why is it better?

Comment: When you use getComputedStyle, if you had set the display value for the element with a class or some other CSS selector, that would be returned instead of the display.style approach which only recognizes any inline styles. getComputedStyle is more accurate in terms of recognizing all possible scenarios in which a style could be applied to an element.

Answer (score 1):

You can also declare a boolean variable like below and based on its state simply show and hide the paragraph text.

```
var isShown = false;

function show_hide(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (isShown)
    {
        isShown = false;
        e.style.display = 'none';
    }
  else
    {
        e.style.display = 'block';
        isShown = true;
    }
 }
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8L9g6dsf/5/)

Answer (score -1):

Your logic is wrong.

```js
function show_hide(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'none' || e.style.display==''){
     e.style.display = 'block';
      }
  else{
      e.style.display = 'none';
     }
   }
```

```css
.hidden{
        display:none;
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="show_hide('text_to_show_hide')" value="Show/Hide">
 
<p id="text_to_show_hide" class="hidden">This is the text that I want to show/hide.</p>
```